# How to login with new user and fix error : ": No such file or directory"?

Tags: ssh, root, su, useradd

I created a user with root access

```
useradd -ou 0 -g 0 myuser -p [12345]
```

when I try to su to the new user, I get:

```
: No such file or directory
```

when I want to connect as that user via ssh, I get:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

So, I checked `/etc/passwd`:

```
myuser:x:0:0::/home/myuser:/bin/bash
```

To test it, I created another user without root access and it worked very well.

I also added this line to `/etc/sudoers` but it still doesn't work:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
myuser ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I then changed `PermitRootLogin` in sshd_config but still no luck :(

How can I create a user with root access and ssh into my machine as that user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours it's finally done!
I just create new user like this :

```
useradd -ou 0 myuser -p [#hash-password]
```

and then I changed `PermitRootLogin yes` in this path : `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

easy as pie :)

Comment: This will still give you the error about no home directory.

Answer (score 4):

Usually on Linux there is only one user `root`, and on Ubuntu it is deactivated. Instead it is a better idea to add all users that should have administrative privilieges to the group `sudo` by executing

```
adduser username sudo
```

as root. That allows them to execute commands as root by typing

```
sudo command
```

and get a root shell by

```
sudo -i
```

On top op that, you don't have to enable root login for ssh that way.

The home directory probably wasn't created because you added a user with an id (`0`) that already existed. Avoid setting the userid and groupid manually.

---

**Step-by-Step how-to create an admin user:**

1. `sudo adduser username`
2. `sudo adduser username sudo`

Comment: thanks for your reply , first how to enable root login for ssh? second I want to create an user with root access why I can't ???

Comment: Have you set a password for `root`?  Afaik there's no way to create a second root user, but the approach with groups I described is even better imho.

Comment: yeah I set that, actually I create an user with adm group but again I can't login to the new user ! why ?

Comment: did you add the user like I write above (I edited the answer)?

Comment: I done that yes, in step 2, when I checked the passwd it didn't change so I open the passwd manually and change group to adm (4) but it didn't work again

Comment: strange... I wonder if you messed something up with `useradd -ou 0 -g 0 myuser -p [12345]`

Comment: instead of 12345 I wrote hash code , and when I started again with you I delete that user with userdel command, thanks anyway 1++

Comment: This is not right....`adm` group is solely related to log files permission..you might be talking about `admin` group but that is deprecated..putting the user only in `sudo` group will be enough..

Comment: @heemayl: Thank you, I didn't know that :-) Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

The first error is because you created a user whose home directory doesn't exist. This is one of the reasons why you should always use `adduser` instead of `useradd`. As explained in `man useradd`:

```
   useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian,
   administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead.
```

One of the features of `adduser` is that it automatically creates the home directory for you. So, what you wanted to run was:

```
    sudo adduser --gid 0 --uid 0 username
```

The next issue is that you have to allow root login. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

to

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Then, restart the `ssh` server:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: Allowing remote root logins is a bad idea. [luckyromo's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/639082/20358) is more secure. Ideally, you don't want to allow password login, either, instead using RSA keys. There are bots out there brute-forcing root logins on any ssh server they can find.

Comment: Granted, this answer is precisely what the OP was asking for.